# Issue with screen on MacBook pro

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

Was just using my machine for 5 mins, felt it getting quite warm - and then the screen failed. Attached a screenshot. Any ideas?? Many thanks [image]

Comment: Is it a 2011 MacBook Pro? If so, then the AMD GPU has developed a well known fault. If not, then what year is it?

Comment: No, it's 2019. I have just observed that the screen is fine when opened to about 25 degrees. Beyond that, I get the symptoms in the photo

Comment: That points to a flex cable dying. Depending on how comfortable you are with electronics, you could try to repair it yourself or get a nearby shop to do it for you.

Comment: So I'm kind of fine with electronics, and I've seen the cable is about £12. But seems I have to remove the display panel to replace it. Does that sound right to you? Hopefully a local shop could try? Seems like apple just want to replace the entire display unit!!

Comment: Within 3 years should still be within warranty for lots of places. I'd suggest to Apple that they need to replace this for free.

Comment: Sadly I'm in the UK. I don't think our consumer rights are that strong. I'm anticipating them telling me I need a while new display unit, which seems to cost almost half of what I paid for the machine!!